# importing pandas, numpy 'module' object has no attribute 'Integral'

Tags: numpy, pandas, anaconda, python-import

I have been working with a script using pandas, numpy, and scikit-learn that worked just fine.

Out of the blue (for sure I did something, but I do not know what) I am getting this error message:

```
C:\Users\xx\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:/Users/xxxx/create_predictions_2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/xxxx/create_predictions_2.py", line 5, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from . import numerictypes as nt
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 968, in <module>
_register_types()
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 965, in _register_types
numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Integral'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am doing the following imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

As you can see, I am using Anaconda on python 3.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you perhaps name a file `numbers.py`?

Comment: Please add `import numbers` and then `print(numbers.__file__)` to the very start of your program, and report the output -- probably you're shadowing `numbers.py` with a file of your own.

Comment: Hi fokls, yes - this was the problem. I inadvertently created a numbers.py file. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is due to some **jython** calls means you tried to create a jython program executed python code in java then without destroying the process you tried to call a python program from python interpreter.